# I need to add few things in my Java code

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
public class UG3 {
    private static Scanner sc;

        public static void main (String[] arg) {

            String indata = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ange cylinderns" + " radie och höjd i CM:"); // inputs information, radius first and heights comes after.
            sc = new Scanner(indata);

            double radie  = sc.nextDouble(); // radius
            double Höjd = sc.nextDouble(); // height
            double volym = Math.PI * Math.pow(radie,2) * Höjd;

            NumberFormat r = NumberFormat.getInstance();

            r.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
            r.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Volymen av cylindern är "+ r.format(volym) +"CM^3"); // outputs the results
    } //main
} //Cylinder
```

This is a code that inputs information and the results is the volume of a cylinder.

But I want to add something to it.

The class must have a separate method that solves the volume.

The program should ask, calculate, if more cylinders needs to be solved.

I'm not really sure how I am supposed to do that. I have never written a program bigger than one class. :S

Comment: Does that mean you think we are here to do your home work?

Comment: If you are sure, as you said, go step by step and you'll get it. I am sure.

Comment: Why do you assume that i want you to write the code for me?

Comment: I simply wanted someone to explain how and where I should put my thought to so I can make it work.

Comment: As I stated earlier, I'm still a beginner so I don't know a lot of Java.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the scanner was quite useless in this situation. Go PANE or go HOME! I don't know what language you're using in your code so I went ahead and translated it into english based on your specifications. I used your same structure but got rid of some very obsolete and useless variables. If you need info as to what anything does I'll be here all week!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;
public class Help_Input {
        public static void main (String[] arg) {

            String radius = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Radius");
            String height = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Height");// inputs information, radius first and heights comes after.

            int rad = Integer.parseInt(radius);
            int hei = Integer.parseInt(height);
            double volume = Math.PI * Math.pow(rad,2) * hei;

            NumberFormat r = NumberFormat.getInstance();

            r.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
            r.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The volume of the cylinder is approximately "+ r.format(volume) +"CM^3"); // outputs the results
            int ag = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to find the volume of a cylinder once more?", "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(ag == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                main(arg);
            };
    } //main
//Cylinder
}
```

Comment: yeah that simplified things. ^^

It's just that you missed: 


"The class must have a separate method that solves the volume."

Answer (score 0):

import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;

public class UG3 {

```
public static void main (String[] arg) {



        String radius = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Radius");
        String height = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Height");// input radius and height.

    if (radius >= 1 && height >= 1) {  // trying to make sure that the user inputs information otherwise it will cancel.

        int rad = Integer.parseInt(radius);
        int hei = Integer.parseInt(height);
        double volume = Math.PI * Math.pow(rad,2) * hei;

        NumberFormat r = NumberFormat.getInstance();

        r.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        r.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The volume of the cylinder is approximately "+ r.format(volume) +"CM^3"); // output results.

        int yes = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to find the volume of a cylinder once more?", "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if(yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) { 
            main(arg);
        }

        else  {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You'r welcome! \n \n Click 'OK' to exit", "Cylinder.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }


    else { // cancel.

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry but you have to enter radius and height to complete the task."); 
    }




 } //main
// trying to solve the problem in a different method.
/* 
 public static double getVolume(double radius, double height){
     double volume = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius,2) * height;
     return(volume);
 }
*/
```

}//Cylinder

Changed my code to yours and trying to add 2 more things, I hope It's ok?

Trying to solve the volume in a new method but dont know how I'm suppoed to do that. And somehow I'm getting stuck at the first If statement.